# Android emulator with 2.2 AVD continuously generates skia logs

Tags: android, android-emulator

Typically after some network operation my android emulator starts emitting following logs continuously.  It's making difficult to see logs of other programs in logcat. what could be issue. I'm performing some network operation in my application using AndroidHttpClient. But my program does not do anything related to image download.

What could be issue ?

08-31 11:23:44.504: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.584: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.614: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.644: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.684: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.824: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.924: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:44.964: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.004: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.054: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.094: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.134: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.174: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.224: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.254: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.324: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.354: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-31 11:23:45.444: DEBUG/skia(180): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null